# Resolving path of child modules in parent pom

Tags: java, maven

I am adding two `modules` in my `parent pom`. I am able to resolve the dependency of one of the `module` because the parent `module` and the child `module` are both in the same `workspace`. 
The parent is in:
`C:/Workspace/Web/ProjectOne/parent`. Two child modules are in:
`C:/Workspace/Web/ProjectOne/project1` 
`C:/Workspace/Project/Servlet/project2`

For `project1` when I provide the path `../project1` in the `parent pom`, the `build` is successful. It is due to it shares the same `workspace` with parent. However, I am unable to resolve the path for `project2` since it is in different folder. I tried adding path `../project2`, the path becomes something like this: `C:/Workspace/Web/ProjectOne/parent/../project2`. I am not sure why those two dots appear like that. I thought it will move up the directory by two folders. So, the `build` fails, as the path is not correct.

I will appreciate anyone's help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get from `C:/Workspace/Web/ProjectOne/parent` to `C:/Workspace/Project/Servlet/project2` you need to specify this path: `../../../Project/Servlet/project2`.

However, it's generally recommended to avoid this kind of project separation. Let's say you keep everything from `Web/ProjectOne` in one SCM repository and `Project/Servlet` in another. How do you version/release them together, which repository do you tag when? There are too many complications with this approach. You're better of getting them closer to each other. If you cannot, you should probably separate their build lifecycles and simply use one of them as a maven dependency for the other.

Comment: Can you please explain how you came up with that path.. Thanks.

Comment: @YogeshGhimire This is how relative paths work [in most operating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#Absolute_and_relative_paths).